# Google cloud DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, cloud, google

Google cloud DNS gives four nameservers, which appear to have IPv4 addresses. If an IPv6-only client tries to access a website, which uses Google Cloud nameservers, would the domain name get resolved to the concerned IPv6 address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS names are resolved to their respective query types. If you query a DNS for an `A` record, then you'll get the IPv4 address. If you query for an `AAAA` record then you'll get the IPv6 address.

If you take a look Google's nameservers *also* have IPv6 DNS addresses, so the IPv6-only client should be able to reach them. You can check that by using the `dig` command on a linux machine:

```
dig nameserver_address AAAA
```

If the client queries the for the `AAAA` record then it'll resolve to the IPv6 address and it should then be able to connect to it.